# Return one result from two GraphQL Resolvers

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I am looking to combine the results from two queries into one for my GraphQL schema. I have a `stock` and `price` type, each of which resolves individually but I don't know how to combine the results.
Here is my `typedefs` and resolvers`:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query{
        stock(symbol: String!): Stock
        price(symbol: String!): Price
    }

    type Stock {
        companyName: String
        exchange: String
        industry: String
        sector: String
        tags: [String]
        cost: Price
    }

    type Price {
        cost: String
    }

`;

const resolvers = {
    Query:{
        stock: async(root, {symbol}, {dataSources}) =>{
            return dataSources.myapi.getSomeData(symbol)
        },
        // dont have a name for your property? ADD ONE!
        price: async(root, {symbol}, {dataSources})=>{
            return {'cost': dataSources.myapi.getAPrice(symbol)}
        }
    }
};
```

If I run a query like so, I get `null` for stock price:

```
query{
  stock(symbol:"aapl"){
    tags
    cost{
      cost
    }
  }
}
```

The result is like so:

```
{
  "data": {
    "stock": {
      "tags": [
        "Technology",
        "Consumer Electronics",
        "Computer Hardware"
      ],
      "cost": null
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I run a query for price, I get the expected outcome for the price:

```
query{
  price(symbol:"aapl"){
      cost
  }
}
```

I am using [datasources](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources.html) and the file looks like so:

```
class MyApi extends RESTDataSource{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.baseURL = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0';
    }

    async getAPrice(symbol){
        return this.get(`/stock/${symbol}/price`);
    }

    async getSomeData(symbol){
        return this.get(`/stock/${symbol}/company`)
    }
}

module.exports = MyApi;
```

I wanted to know why this is happening. Is there something that I am not doing well, or lack of understanding in a certain way GraphQL handles resolvers?

Would it be recommended to return both queries in the resolver through a promise? I am not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have will work with the following adjustment to your resolvers:

```
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        stock: async(root, {symbol}, {dataSources}) => {
            const stock = await dataSources.myapi.getSomeData(symbol)
            return {...stock, symbol: symbol}
        },
        // dont have a name for your property? ADD ONE!
        price: async(root, {symbol}, {dataSources}) => {
            const cost = await dataSources.myapi.getAPrice(symbol)
            return {cost: cost}
        }
    },
    Stock: {
      cost: async (stockWithSymbol, args, {dataSources}) => {
        const cost = await dataSources.myapi.getAPrice(stockWithSymbol.symbol)
        return {cost: cost}
      }
    }
};
```

The bottom `Stock` block tells GraphQL how to resolve the `cost` field on the `Stock` type. Notice that in the root stock query resolver, I'm also spreading the response with the symbol so that it is available in the first argument of the cost field resolver. You may have a better way of loading price given the stock information, but just going off the schema shown.

Comment: I am getting an error  for `unexpected identifier` on the line with `const cost = await dataSources.myapi.getAPrice(stockWithSymbol.symbol)`. Did the solution work for you? Datasources is underlined in my console as the unexpected identifier.

Comment: Forgot to add async to the nested resolver. It was complaining about using await without async

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this further and what you referred to as the "bottom stock block" is called a `nested resolver` in GraphQL terms. Here is what I came up with for my additional resolver:

```
Stock:{
    price: async(company, args, {dataSources})=>{
        return {'cost': dataSources.myapi.getAPrice(company.symbol)}
    }
}
```

Does this seem to be the same thing?